# Fastest Algorithm to Find the Minimum Sum of Absolute Differences through List Rotation

Tags: python, algorithm, discrete-mathematics

By rotating 2 lists either from left to right, Find the smallest possible sum of the absolute value of the differences between each corresponding item in the two lists given they're the ***same*** length.

Rotation Sample:

```
List [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5] rotated to the left = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 0]

List [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5] rotated to the right= [5, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Sum of Absolute Difference:

```
List 1 = [1, 2, 3, 4]
List 2 = [5, 6, 7, 8]

Sum of Abs. Diff. = |1-5| + |2-6| + |3-7| + |4-8| = 16
```

Once again, for any arbitrary length of list and integer values, task is to look for the least possible sum by simply rotating to the left/right of either or both lists.

I had no problem with the rotation and acquiring of the minimum sum of absolute difference. I just want to know the smarter approach since my algorithm checks for every possible combination which is quite slow.

Here is my bruteforce approach:

```
list1 = [45, 21, 64, 33, 49]
list2 = [90, 12, 77, 52, 28]
choices = []                # Put all possible sums into a list to find the minimum value.
for j in range(len(list1)):  # List1 does a full rotation
    total = 0
    for k in range(len(list1)):
        total += abs(list1[k] - list2[k])
    list1.append(list1.pop(0))
    choices.append(total)
print(min(choices))
```

What's a smarter approach? I would appreciate a shorter code and time complexity as well.

I managed to make it faster by applying generators. Credits to @kuriboh for the idea! But since I'm still new in generator implementation, just want to know if this is the best way of implementing it to reduce my time complexity especially for my loop. **Can we still go faster than this configuration?**

```
list1 = [45, 21, 64, 33, 49]
list2 = [90, 12, 77, 52, 28]
choices = []
l = len(list1)
for j in range(l):
    total = sum([abs(int(list1[k])-int(list2[k])) for k in range(l)])
    list1.append(list1.pop(0))
    choices.append(total)
print(min(choices))
```

Comment: Hint: use the differences *bewteen* elements within a list.  For instance, your `list1` above has diffs of [-24, 43, -31, 16, -4].  Look for "fit" patterns with the `list2` diffs.  Note that the improvement works only if you have very large lists; otherwise, the overhead of pattern matching eats up the gains over your **O(N^2)** algorithm.

Comment: @Prune I'm not quite sure if I completely understood your comment, why are we getting the differences of adjacent integers in `list1`?

Comment: Did you create this problem yourself, or why can't you tell us where it's from?

Comment: @superbrain Hi, my bad for not mentioning. Kinda made this up based from some of our CS Problems. I'm trying to learn how to form up faster and shorter solutions to simple problems.

Comment: @Prune I don't see how to take advantage of that, would like to see it :-)

Comment: @Prune Consider `list1` as [45, 21, 64, 33, 49] and `list2` as [28, 12, 52, 90, 77]. The diffs for `list1` are [-24, 43, -31, 16, -4], and the diffs for `list2` are [-16, 40, 38, -13, -49]. Those two diff lists have little in common, even though that's the best rotation for those two lists.

Comment: @user3386109 Is your example for list2 based from my example? Because if it is, that list is impossible to achieve in any of the rotation.

Comment: @muw My `list2` is just a permutation of your list. When using your `list2`, the best rotation is [52, 28, 90, 12, 77], which gives a diff list of [-24, 62, -78, 65, -25]. That diff list makes Prune's idea seem promising. My goal was to permute `list2` in a way that creates a more challenging test case.

Comment: *"I managed to reduce it to O(n)"* - Huh? What are you talking about? That's still the same O(n^2), not O(n).

Comment: @superbrain Oh? I thought that the second for loop operates near constant time. If that's the case, let's just say I managed to make it faster.

Comment: How much faster? And what second for loop?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't cracked the full problem, but in the special case where the input values are all `0` or `1` (or any two different values, or any of `O(1)` different values, but we'll need another idea to get much further than that), we can get an `O(n log n)`-time algorithm by applying fast convolution.

The idea is to compute all of the sums of absolute differences as `List1 * reverse(1 - List2) + (1 - List1) * reverse(List2)` where `1 - List` means doing that operation point-wise and `*` denotes circular convolution (computable in time `O(n log n)` using a pair of FFTs). The definition of circular convolution here is

```
             n-1
             __
             \
(f * g)(i) = /_  f(j) g((i - j) mod n).
             j=0
```

Substituting `List1` for `f` and `reverse(1 - List2)` for `g`, we get

```
                                  n-1
                                  __
                                  \
(List1 * reverse(1 - List2))(i) = /_ List1(j) (1 - List2((n-1-(i-j)) mod n))
                                  j=0

                                  n-1
                                  __
                                  \
                                = /_ List1(j) (1 - List2((j-(i+1)) mod n)).
                                  j=0
```

The product `List1(j) (1 - List2((j-(i+1)) mod n))` is `1` if and only if `List1(j) = 1` and `List2((j-(i+1)) mod n) = 0`, and `0` otherwise. Thus the `i` value of the convolution counts the number of places where `List1` has a `1` offset `i+1` circularly to the left of where `List2` has a `0`. The other convolution counts `0`s corresponding to `1`s. Given our input restrictions, this is the sum of absolute differences.

Code:

```
import numpy


def convolve_circularly(a1, a2):
    return numpy.round(numpy.abs(numpy.fft.ifft(numpy.fft.fft(a1) * numpy.fft.fft(a2))))


def min_sum_abs_diff(a1, a2):
    a1 = numpy.array(a1)
    a2 = numpy.array(a2)[::-1]
    return numpy.min(convolve_circularly(a1, 1 - a2) + convolve_circularly(1 - a1, a2))


def slow_min_sum_abs_diff(a1, a2):
    return min(
        sum(abs(a1[i] - a2[i - k]) for i in range(len(a1))) for k in range(len(a2))
    )


def main():
    n = 100
    for r in range(100000):
        a1 = numpy.random.randint(2, size=n)
        a2 = numpy.random.randint(2, size=n)
        r = min_sum_abs_diff(a1, a2)
        slow_r = slow_min_sum_abs_diff(a1, a2)
        if r != slow_r:
            print(a1, a2, r, slow_r)
            break


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: Good idea to try a simpler problem. Sadly I don't understand the math. Would the Python implementation be simple? Not sure what to do with your equations. Would be nice to see it, and then it could be tested.

Comment: @superbrain I can try to hack one together using NumPy in a while.

Comment: Great, thanks. Looks cool and is indeed very fast (I did some benchmarks in a [new answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64466962/13008439)).

Answer (score 3):

Since Python treats negative indexes as counting from the right end, you could sum the absolute value of `list1` minus (`list2` shifted by k) where 0 ≤ k < len(list1) as

```
sum(abs(list1[i] - list2[i - k]) for i in range(len(list1)))
```

If you want the minimum of all of these values

```
length = len(list1)
min(sum(abs(list1[i] - list2[i - k]) for i in range(length))
    for k in range(length))
```

This code is still O(n^2), but there is a lot less pushing and popping going on.

I really can't think of any way to make the algorithm faster than O(n^2).

Comment: Minus is done with `-` :-P. And I'm pretty sure those index subtractions cost much more time than the pop+append.

Comment: @superbrain the index operations definitely do not take more time than the pop and append. The `pop(0)` call is `O(n)`, as it is removing the first element of the list.

Comment: @EvilTak They definitely do. Overall, pop is done only n times, while the index operations are done n^2 times. So they're doing the same "amount of work", but the pops do so at a far faster lower level.

Comment: @superbrain normally I would disagree with you, but given that this is Python, there is a chance that you are right. Still find it hard to believe that the overhead incurred by `n` extra subtractions outweighs the cost of the `memcpy` for pop. I'd definitely recommend that OP profile both solutions and pick which one works best for them. Regardless, this answer does do away with the redundant `choices` list, appending to which at every iteration would incur quite a bit of overhead.

Comment: @EvilTak Why quite a bit of overhead for the append? That's cheap.

Comment: @user3386109 I was hoping you saw that! The edit summary abuse was totally worth it. You wouldn't believe my euphoria at being able to reply to you via another potential edit after seeing your edit summary...

Comment: @superbrain Not if the backing array has to be resized. Resizing == `realloc` + `memcpy`. No matter how cheap you may consider it to be, it's still more expensive than doing nothing at all (or even using a pre-sized array).

Comment: I'm kinda lost, so @superbrain means to say that my code runs faster?

Comment: Thank you @EvilTak for fixing my code.  I thought I could just type it without using an IDE.  Never again.

Comment: @FrankYelling I appreciate your contribution, but since this still traverses the whole list (although arguably a bit faster), I'm kinda looking for something that necessarily check every combination in the list.

Comment: Understood. I realized I wasn't giving you a breakthrough. Do you have for believing a better algorithm exist, or just asking?

Comment: (Correction for my last comment, I'm kinda looking for something that DOESNT necessarily check every combination in the list)

And yes, I actually have an idea, bot not really a breakthrough. Instead of just getting the sum of one pair for every iteration, what if we get the sum of TWO pairs?

Eg. Sum of list1[0] and list2[0], AND sum of list1[length/2+i] and list2[length/2+i]

Would that really do much for larger n?

Comment: I modified my code to search only have of the list, but gets the sum of two pairs. Please check.

Comment: @EvilTak The list sufficiently overallocates so that appends are amortized O(1) and overall O(n). Plus that's a high-speed C-level O(n). The rest of the code does O(n^2) *slow* Python-level operations. Multiple. The appends are super cheap in comparison. I just benchmarked with n=1000, the OP's original code took about 124 ms, Frank's took about 150 ms (that's slower!, not sure why it got upvoted/accepted), and the appends took about 0.03 ms. That's 0.024% overhead, you call that "quite a bit"? https://repl.it/repls/AquamarineModestTrapezoids#main.py

Comment: @superbrain. Thanks for the numbers. Good to have data.  Original poster didn't originally explain that he was working in a constrained environment in which the only point was to get below an artificial time limit.  My code was (I hope) upvoted because it was clean, simple, and let Python handle all the busywork.

Comment: @FrankYellin Yeah, `sum` and `min` on generators is nicer, and the `- k` is less code than the pop+append. You do take over the busywork of the rotation that way, though. From built-in C to your own Python. For a question that literally starts with the word "Fastest" (in the title, and it was there from the start), it's somewhat disappointing to see an answer that's slower than the original. The differing indices also prevent usage of `zip`. Added that as another answer now.

Comment: @superbrain thanks for the data! Goes to show how much I underestimated Python's slowness. I knew Python was slow, but I didn't know that it'd be *that* slow :)

Comment: My bad for missing what's going on here, got a bit occupied yesterday. Yes. I also noticed @FrankYellin's approach was kinda slower than my approach. So far, I guess superbrain's code works the best.

Answer (score 3):

An optimized mix of your original and Frank's accepted answer:

```
min(list1.append(list1.pop(0)) or
    sum(abs(x - y) for x, y in zip(list1, list2))
    for _ in list1)
```

Bit dirty to have the rotation in there like that, but hey, you're asking for "Fastest" :-)

Benchmark with lists of length 1000:

```
    original     Frank_Yellin   superb_rain  
     127 ms         164 ms         125 ms    
     140 ms         170 ms         117 ms    
     134 ms         166 ms         116 ms    
     124 ms         161 ms         126 ms    
     135 ms         164 ms         126 ms
```

Benchmark code:

```
from timeit import repeat
from random import shuffle

def original(list1, list2):
    choices = []                # Put all possible sums into a list to find the minimum value.
    for j in range(len(list1)):  # List1 does a full rotation
        total = 0
        for k in range(len(list1)):
            total += abs(list1[k] - list2[k])
        list1.append(list1.pop(0))
        choices.append(total)
    return min(choices)

def Frank_Yellin(list1, list2):
    length = len(list1)
    return min(sum(abs(list1[i] - list2[i - k]) for i in range(length))
    for k in range(length))

def superb_rain(list1, list2):
    return min(list1.append(list1.pop(0)) or
               sum(abs(x - y) for x, y in zip(list1, list2))
               for _ in list1)

funcs = [
    (10, original),
    (10, Frank_Yellin),
    (10, superb_rain),
    ]

list1 = list(range(1000))
list2 = list1.copy()
shuffle(list2)

for _, f in funcs:
    print(f(list1, list2))

for _, f in funcs:
    print(f.__name__.center(15), end='')
print()

for _ in range(5):
    for number, f in funcs:
        t = min(repeat(lambda: f(list1, list2), number=number)) / number
        print('%8d ms    ' % (t * 1e3), end='')
    print()
```

Comment: Love this. I thought my code was optimized. I kinda missed the fact that I'm typecasting the lists into integer EVERY iteration. What you did is better. Well done!

Comment: @muw Ha, I didn't even realize you did that. What was the point of that? Btw, I think [David's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64444913/13008439) is the most promising and only interesting one.

Comment: I honestly don't understand his process yet, but if you think his idea is better than yours, then I'll pick his answer.

Comment: @muw I don't understand his solution, either, but the idea is good and the tests convince me and benchmarks show it's very fast (I'll post another answer about that).

Answer (score 2):

Benchmarks with [David Eisenstat's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64444913/13008439) and two NumPy solutions from me.

500 random ints 0 or 1:

```
  189.62414 ms  slow_min_sum_abs_diff          # Like Frank's
   49.75403 ms  less_slow_min_sum_abs_diff     # My NumPy
   10.13092 ms  lesser_slow_min_sum_abs_diff   # My Numpy
    0.85030 ms  min_sum_abs_diff               # David's
    0.27434 ms  array_conversion               # for comparison
```

1000 random ints 0 or 1:

```
  857.02381 ms  slow_min_sum_abs_diff
  100.26820 ms  less_slow_min_sum_abs_diff
   28.55692 ms  lesser_slow_min_sum_abs_diff
    1.67077 ms  min_sum_abs_diff
    0.49301 ms  array_conversion
```

1000 random ints from -10<sup>6</sup> to 10<sup>6</sup> (without David's, as it's not made for that and would produce wrong results):

```
  829.18451 ms  slow_min_sum_abs_diff
   89.97418 ms  less_slow_min_sum_abs_diff
   22.69516 ms  lesser_slow_min_sum_abs_diff
```

I don't understand David's solution, but his own verification is convincing and I did some more myself, comparing each faster solution with the next-slower one (that's actually why I wrote my NumPy solutions, so I could test David's with larger inputs):

```
passed: less_slow_min_sum_abs_diff (220 tests with n=100)
passed: lesser_slow_min_sum_abs_diff (89 tests with n=300)
passed: min_sum_abs_diff (146 tests with n=1000)
passed: min_sum_abs_diff (5 tests with n=10000)
```

Benchmarks done on repl.it's Python 3.8.2 64-bit.

The code:

```
import numpy
from timeit import repeat, default_timer as timer


def array_conversion(a1, a2):
    a1 = numpy.array(a1)
    a2 = numpy.array(a2)


def convolve_circularly(a1, a2):
    return numpy.round(numpy.abs(numpy.fft.ifft(numpy.fft.fft(a1) * numpy.fft.fft(a2))))


def min_sum_abs_diff(a1, a2):
    a1 = numpy.array(a1)
    a2 = numpy.array(a2)[::-1]
    return numpy.min(convolve_circularly(a1, 1 - a2) + convolve_circularly(1 - a1, a2))


def slow_min_sum_abs_diff(a1, a2):
    return min(
        sum(abs(a1[i] - a2[i - k]) for i in range(len(a1))) for k in range(len(a2))
    )


def less_slow_min_sum_abs_diff(a1, a2):
    a1 = numpy.array(a1)
    a2 = numpy.array(a2)
    return min(
        numpy.abs(a1 - numpy.roll(a2, k)).sum()
        for k in range(len(a2))
    )


def lesser_slow_min_sum_abs_diff(a1, a2):
    n = len(a2)
    a1 = numpy.array(a1)
    a2 = numpy.concatenate((a2, a2))
    return min(
        numpy.abs(a1 - a2[k:k+n]).sum()
        for k in range(n)
    )


def random_arrays(n):
    a1 = numpy.random.randint(2, size=n).tolist()
    a2 = numpy.random.randint(2, size=n).tolist()
    return a1, a2


def verify(candidate, reference, n, timelimit=1):
    t0 = timer()
    count = 0
    while timer() - t0 < timelimit:
        a1_orig, a2_orig = random_arrays(n)
        a1, a2 = a1_orig.copy(), a2_orig.copy()
        expect = reference(a1, a2)
        assert a1 == a1_orig and a2 == a2_orig
        result = candidate(a1, a2)
        assert a1 == a1_orig and a2 == a2_orig
        if result != expect:
            print('wrong:')
            print('  expected', expect, 'by', reference.__name__)
            print('  got', result, 'by', candidate.__name__)
            print('  a1:', a1)
            print('  a2:', a2)
            break
        count += 1
    else:
        print('passed:', candidate.__name__, f'({count} tests with {n=})')


def main():
    if 1:
        verify(less_slow_min_sum_abs_diff, slow_min_sum_abs_diff, 100)
        verify(lesser_slow_min_sum_abs_diff, less_slow_min_sum_abs_diff, 300)
        verify(min_sum_abs_diff, lesser_slow_min_sum_abs_diff, 1000)
        verify(min_sum_abs_diff, lesser_slow_min_sum_abs_diff, 10000)
        print()

    funcs = [
        (10, slow_min_sum_abs_diff),
        (100, less_slow_min_sum_abs_diff),
        (100, lesser_slow_min_sum_abs_diff),
        (1000, min_sum_abs_diff),
        (1000, array_conversion),
    ]

    a1, a2 = random_arrays(1000)

    for _ in range(3):
        for number, func in funcs:
            t = min(repeat(lambda: func(a1, a2), number=number)) / number
            print('%11.5f ms ' % (t * 1e3), func.__name__)
        print()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
    print('done')
```